# Device always boots in recovery mode, but apparently there is no recovery partition

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, reboot, recovery-mode, boot, bootloader

We have a [BSNL Penta IS709c](http://www.pantel.in/tablet/t-pad-is709c-42.html) (cheapest tablet currently available / Oct 2012) running Android 4.0.

Feeling adventurous, I issued `reboot recovery` through `adb` and the device tried to reboot in *recovery mode*. However turns out that there is probably no recovery partition and the device is stuck at following screen. Rebooting the device doesn't help and it always boots to following screen.

So, what can I do to boot it back in normal mode? I'd also like to point out that this device does **not** has *Volume Up* and *Volume Down* buttons. Available 4 physical buttons are *Power/Home/Menu/Back*.

[image: Android recovery mode without recovery partition]

Comment: Is the battery removable? Pulling the battery might help. Alternatively, can you connect the tablet to a PC with the Android SDK installed and try doing `adb reboot`?

Comment: Do any of the buttons do anything at this screen? As far as I know this is the stock Android Recovery.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi No battery is not removable (I might open the case as last resort though). I drained the battery by keeping it switched on, but still the same result.

@ChinmayKanchi Device is not detected by PC (not listed in `lsusb`).

@ZnewmaN None of the buttons seem to do anything, except of course the power button. I also tried some combination of the buttons but no success.

Comment: Is it within warranty? I'd just return it to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Press the power button for 10 seconds and its going to reboot itself if you have not corrupted any system partitions. Or try adb reboot bootloader and from there select the start button and press it with the power key.

Comment: 1. The power button trick doesn't work and no I've *not* corrupted any system partitions. All that I did was issuing `reboot recovery` through `adb`.

2. Device is no more being recognised by Linux, so can not use any `adb` commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is a software issue and it's fixed in a more recent firmware version that can be downloaded from http://www.pantel.in/DriverDownloads (look for the IS709C firmware download).